# Google sheet - How to search for a value in a sheet, copy a value and paste in another worksheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I use a form with a simple question.

Question 1: Which channel has an issue? (The user has to choose an answer in a list) 
Question 2: "what is the issue" (and the answer is a free comment)

Now the answers are sent to a specific worksheet named "answers" with:

- Column A: timestamp
- Column B: Answer question 1
- Column C: Answer question 2

In this same Google sheet, I have another worksheet (GLOBAL) with the global channel list in column A, and a column for the specific issue comment.

As I didn't find a way to provide the answer of a google form in a specific column of a sheet, I am searching for a way to:

1. "start when a new answer is added in the "answers sheet"
2. "identify the channel recently added and search for this value on the "GLOBAL" worksheet"
3. When the value is found, I want to add the value of column B and column C of "answers sheet" to the corresponding columns on the "GLOBAL" worksheet.

Do you have any idea on how I can do that as I am not an expert

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you asking for but **`VLOOKUP`** is your friend:

> **`=VLOOKUP(F2, A1:C, 2, 0)`**
>
> look for A2 in range A1:C and return 2nd column from that range.
>
> **`=VLOOKUP(D4, sheet2!A2:B, {2,3}, 0)`**
>
> look for D4 in range A2:B of other sheet called "sheet2" and return 2nd and 3rd column from sheet2
>
> **`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(X2:X5, C1:C, 1, 0)`**
>
> look for range X2:X5 in C1:C and return 1st column from range C1:C if there is match
>
> **`=VLOOKUP(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A1"), IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet5!F1:X"), {2,6,7}, 0)`**
>
> etc...

Comment: Thank you,the problem is that I need that only the "latest" value has to be written in the destination sheet.So for example, if the channel "ABC" has been updated 3 times, I need that only the latest comment have to be copied to the destination sheet. Is it possible ?

Comment: @user2882219 see these answers: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123974/186471